# Programmatically activate loudspeaker when receiving phone call

Tags: android

hey..i plan to add a function to my app which will auto switch on the loudspeaker when the user received phone call..

here are part of my codes:

```
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
              //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK; 

              setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL); 
               am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
               am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
          boolean check = am.isSpeakerphoneOn();
          Toast.makeText(Speaker.this, "LoudSpeaker On: "+ check,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and i already added the permission for MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in the manifest..however..the speakerphone didnt manage to turn on..can anyone kindly give a helping hand on this problem..thanks in advance..by the way..this app was implement in android 2.1

Comment: anyone can give a help?? thanks

Comment: i have the same code as above and speaker on on-incoming call

Answer (score 2):

try to hold 500 ms before turning it on ..

so it will be something like :

```
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500); // Delay 0,5 seconds to handle better turning on
                                // loudspeaker
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        boolean check = am.isSpeakerphoneOn();
        Toast.makeText(Speaker.this, "LoudSpeaker On: " + check,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

btw I have Xperia 4.1.2 and your initial code is working without any issue ..